# Post reviews to Google Business Profile

Tags: google-api, google-developer-tools, google-business

I am creating an app that allows users to rate businesses (who are our customers). The businesses would like the user reviews to be cross-posted to their Google Business Profile in addition to appearing as an in-app review in our ecosystem. Does anyone know if there is a way to embed a Google-blessed widget in a mobile app that would allow posting a review to the Google Business Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New reviews can only be created via Google Maps UI or the Google Knowledge Graph UI. The Google Business Profile APIs only support listing and replying to reviews (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews).

So the closest way to get directly to posting a new review would be via this URL pattern:

[https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=<PLACE_ID>](https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=%3CPLACE_ID%3E)

e.g.
https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw